# While loop behaving unexpectedly in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, finch

I'm trying to get my loop to go over and over again until the user types in "quit" then it will quit.

Basically I'm trying to get my Finch robot to change nose color depending on how it's positioned, but I'm confused on how to get it to allow the user to position it again after it has already been positioned so that the nose color can change color multiple times.  When it first runs the Finch will execute the code but quits immediately afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
public class finch {

public static final int INCREASE = 20;
public static final int SEC = 1000;
public static final int MAXSPEED = 255;
public static final int HALFSEC = 500;

public static Finch myFinch;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFinch = new Finch();

    Menu();

}

public static void Menu() {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your choice:" + "");

    int input;
    int input1;

    boolean flag=true;
    while(flag){

        System.out.println("1.\t" + "Rolling" + "Finch");
        System.out.println("2.\t" + "Obedient" + "Finch");
        System.out.println("3.\t" + "Exit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
        System.out.println();


        input = console.nextInt();
        flag=false;
        if (input == 1) {
            //input = DarkFinch;
            System.out.println("Position the Finch \"down\" or \"up\" to change nose color");
            rolling(myFinch);
        } else if (input == 2) {
            // input = ChasetheFinch;
            //  System.out.println("Chase The Finch");
        } else if (input == 3) {
            //    input = Exit;
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
        } else {
            //    System.out.println("Try again");

            flag=true;
            /*  return Menu(); */
        }
    }
}

public static boolean rolling(Finch myFinch) {//This method will change the Finches nose color depending on the Finches position.
    //"up" = place the finch upright standing on its tail



    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {


        while (myFinch.isBeakDown() || myFinch.isBeakUp()) {
            if (myFinch.isBeakDown()) {
                myFinch.setLED(0,0,255,3000);
            } else if (myFinch.isBeakUp()) {
                myFinch.setLED(255,0,0,3000);
            } else {
                myFinch.setLED(0,0,0,5000);
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You have it quit unless the input is 1, 2, or 3. How about you try setting the flag only if the input is "quit"? You won't be able to use `nextInt()` for that, though.

Comment: Why can't you just put `flag=false` inside only `case 3`? So in all other cases it keeps looping

Comment: When the user types "1" in method "Menu" it will call the method "rolling" and I want to be able to re-position my Finch robot multiple times so the color changes depending if its facing up, down or forward and after each position i want to prompt the user with the sentence "please reposition the robot" so that the robot reacts if it changes position but if the user types in "quit" then it will exit out of the code

Comment: @GoldRoger what do you mean case 3?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set your flag = false before the condition on the input value. Set it to false in the if(input == 3) case